# Second 'for' loop being ignored after first 'for' loop in program that calculate the scalar product in c

Tags: c, arrays, dynamic, malloc, allocation

I am trying to scan two vector input from the keyboard, and then create a function that will return the scalar product of the two vectors. However when I run the program, as soon as it scans the first vector in the first for loop, the program ends and the scalar product is 0. I don't understand why it doesn't let me scan the second vector. This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

double scalarproduct(double *v, double *w, int n){
    double vw[n];
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        vw[i] = (v[i] * w[i]); 
    }
    double scalprod = 0; 
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        scalprod += vw[i];
    }
    return scalprod;
}

int main(){
    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    double *v; 
    v = (double *) malloc(sizeof(double) * n);
    double *w;
    w = (double *) malloc(sizeof(double) * n);
    for(int i = 0; i < 0; i++){
        scanf("%lf", &v[i]);       
    }  
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        scanf("%lf", &w[i]);
    }
    printf("Scalar product=%lf\n", scalarproduct(v,w,n));
    return 0; 
 }
```

This is what the input should look like:

```
3
1.1
2.5
3.0
1.0
1.0
1.0
```

However it only lets me input until 3.0, and then the program skips the second for loop to the print statement. How can i fix this?

Comment: `for(int i = 0; i < 0; i++)` -- might want to change the limit of the loop that scans the input for the first vector. `:)`

Comment: Indeed it's the *first* loop that is skipped ;)

Comment: Side note - you want to use 'calloc' instead of malloc. This will zero the allocated memory, eliminating lot of potential pitfalls. The common method is 'double *v = (double *) calloc(n, sizeof(*v)) ;

Answer (score 0):

The first `for` loop has a typo: `for(int i = 0; i < 0; i++)` it stops immediately.

It should be:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
```

Note also these remarks:

- you should check the return values of `scanf()`
- you should check for memory allocation failure
- you do not need to store the individual products into a local array, which might be very long and pose problems.
- you should free allocated memory.

Here is a corrected and simplified version:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

double scalarproduct(double *v, double *w, int n) {
    double scalprod = 0; 
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        scalprod += v[i] * w[i]
    }
    return scalprod;
}

int main() {
    int n;
    if (scanf("%d", &n) == 1 && n > 0) {
        double *v = (double *)malloc(sizeof(double) * n);
        double *w = (double *)malloc(sizeof(double) * n);
        if (v == NULL || w == NULL) {
            printf("cannot allocate memory\n");
            return 1;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            if (scanf("%lf", &v[i]) != 1) {
                printf("invalid input\n");
                return 1;
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            if (scanf("%lf", &w[i]) != 1) {
                printf("invalid input\n");
                return 1;
            }
        }
        printf("Scalar product=%f\n", scalarproduct(v, w, n));
        free(v);
        free(w);
    }
    return 0; 
}
```